# Brackets interface text not appearing

Tags: adobe-brackets

I had to deactivate a whole bunch of fonts on my computer recently. Thought I had avoided deactivating any system fonts, but I seem to have removed the one that the Adobe Brackets app uses, perhaps even the icon font it uses for sidebar icons?

[image]

I'm not sure how this works - if anyone can tell me what fonts this app uses, I can investigate why the interface is not displaying any filenames etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were hitting [this bug with the 'Brackets File Icons' extension](https://github.com/drewbkoch/Brackets-File-Icons/issues/12). The latest version of the extension should work correctly.

If you want to check whether an extension is a problem, just use *Debug > Reload Without Extensions* in the menu - no need to muck with the Application Support folder.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a Extensions folder that was causing the issue - may have been a particular plugin, but don't want to point any fingers at this stage. When I uninstalled Brackets (I'm using MacOSX) I had to remove the Brackets folder in Application Support to remove all Extensions as well.

I reinstalled Brackets, put the Brackets folder back into Application support, opened the app, and everything worked fine again.

To see the location of the Brackets Extensions folder, in Brackets go to Help and choose Show Extensions folder.